# Find $n$th term in the sequence of numbers of the form $m^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$4,8,9,16,25,27,32,36,49,64,81,100,121,125,128,144......$
This is the increasing sequence of the numbers of the form $m^k$.  Where $m,k\ge{2}$ and are positive integers. Can we find the $n$th number in this sequence? Or Can we find which term will be $m^k$?, ie $2^3$ will be $2$nd term. 
I tried finding relation, plotting graph, trial & error but nothing worked.

I know this question is silly but if anyone can help me, please...

Comment: This is [OEIS A001597](http://oeis.org/A001597) which has some references.  They might help

Comment: All the sequences over there have a 128 in them his does not.

Comment: is http://oeis.org/A002760

Comment: A002760 contains only squares and cubes, while the OP sequence contains also higher powers, for example 32 isn't in this OEIS sequence

Comment: @bobbym Sorry guys I had forgotten 128........:(

Comment: @Satvik Mashkaria then I think I will go to the link at the OEIS that Ross Millikan has suggested.